# How do I append an XML attribute using XSLT

Tags: xslt

If I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<Component Id="cmp25217AE65B163B199EDDA7F29198730A" Guid="{DEB29383-8BF1-4FD0-830B-DF8639F4069A}">
<Component Id="cmp93E1B1FFA5A62A43251E23BD65FBAA66" Guid="{76E8B8CE-835D-498E-9330-CE940C9510BF}">
<Component Id="cmp3D7B898C57056B0E87C3A964112BB9D6" Guid="{3BA9A892-C44F-4B2E-B0B9-B732120D35DB}">
```

How do I us XSLT to append 'Win64="yes"' to the end of each element like this:

```
<Component Id="cmp25217AE65B163B199EDDA7F29198730A" Guid="{DEB29383-8BF1-4FD0-830B-DF8639F4069A}" Win64="yes">
<Component Id="cmp93E1B1FFA5A62A43251E23BD65FBAA66" Guid="{76E8B8CE-835D-498E-9330-CE940C9510BF}" Win64="yes">
<Component Id="cmp3D7B898C57056B0E87C3A964112BB9D6" Guid="{3BA9A892-C44F-4B2E-B0B9-B732120D35DB}" Win64="yes">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<xsl:attribute>` element and apply it directly to (inside) the `<xsl:copy>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="Component">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Win64">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Update:** Embedded in an XSLT that otherwise copies the Xml contents, this looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Component">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="Win64">yes</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update 2:** This assumes you only want to add `Win64="yes"` to `<Component>` elements. If this is not the case, you will have to adapt the XPath expression of the `match` attribute in the template that inserts your additional attribute.

**Update 3:** Well-formed input and output documents:

I assume this as the input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <Component Id="cmp25217AE65B163B199EDDA7F29198730A" Guid="{DEB29383-8BF1-4FD0-830B-DF8639F4069A}"/>
    <Component Id="cmp93E1B1FFA5A62A43251E23BD65FBAA66" Guid="{76E8B8CE-835D-498E-9330-CE940C9510BF}"/>
    <Component Id="cmp3D7B898C57056B0E87C3A964112BB9D6" Guid="{3BA9A892-C44F-4B2E-B0B9-B732120D35DB}"/>
</xml>
```

Then, the output of the aforementioned XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <Component Win64="yes" Id="cmp25217AE65B163B199EDDA7F29198730A" Guid="{DEB29383-8BF1-4FD0-830B-DF8639F4069A}" />
  <Component Win64="yes" Id="cmp93E1B1FFA5A62A43251E23BD65FBAA66" Guid="{76E8B8CE-835D-498E-9330-CE940C9510BF}" />
  <Component Win64="yes" Id="cmp3D7B898C57056B0E87C3A964112BB9D6" Guid="{3BA9A892-C44F-4B2E-B0B9-B732120D35DB}" />
</xml>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me... your template produced this:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Component Win64="yes">cmp25217AE65B163B199EDDA7F29198730A{DEB29383-8BF1-4FD0-830B-DF8639F4069A}</Component>
<Component Win64="yes">cmp93E1B1FFA5A62A43251E23BD65FBAA66{76E8B8CE-835D-498E-9330-CE940C9510BF}</Component>
<Component Win64="yes">cmp3D7B898C57056B0E87C3A964112BB9D6{3BA9A892-C44F-4B2E-B0B9-B732120D35DB}</Component>`

Comment: @SteveH. - What processor are you using? Did you have any other templates in your XSLT? It worked fine for me. (+1)

Comment: That output was from XMLSpy. Maybe Saxon would be different, I could try with that.

Comment: @SteveH: I was assuming you just needed the XSLT fragment, as you didn't supply the complete well-formed input Xml document. I have added a complete XSLT example that doesn't really show anything new; it just has the usual copying template that I assumed you'd have anyway. With this new code sample, you have a complete test case; for me it works like this with MSXML tools. Sorry for not stating this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your expertise!  Great implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet will add the attribute to all elements like you requested. Note that the position of the attribute might not be at the end, but that shouldn't matter.

**XML Input** (well-formed)

```
<doc>
    <Component Id="cmp25217AE65B163B199EDDA7F29198730A" Guid="{DEB29383-8BF1-4FD0-830B-DF8639F4069A}"/>
    <Component Id="cmp93E1B1FFA5A62A43251E23BD65FBAA66" Guid="{76E8B8CE-835D-498E-9330-CE940C9510BF}"/>
    <Component Id="cmp3D7B898C57056B0E87C3A964112BB9D6" Guid="{3BA9A892-C44F-4B2E-B0B9-B732120D35DB}"/>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (tested with Xalan and Saxon 6.5.5)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()|comment()|processing-instruction()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="Win64">yes</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc Win64="yes">
   <Component Win64="yes" Id="cmp25217AE65B163B199EDDA7F29198730A" Guid="{DEB29383-8BF1-4FD0-830B-DF8639F4069A}"/>
   <Component Win64="yes" Id="cmp93E1B1FFA5A62A43251E23BD65FBAA66" Guid="{76E8B8CE-835D-498E-9330-CE940C9510BF}"/>
   <Component Win64="yes" Id="cmp3D7B898C57056B0E87C3A964112BB9D6" Guid="{3BA9A892-C44F-4B2E-B0B9-B732120D35DB}"/>
</doc>
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't use `<xsl:copy>` and add more attributes.  I did it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Component">
            <xsl:element name="Component">
                <xsl:attribute name="Id" select="@Id"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="Guid" select="@Guid"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="Win64" select="'yes'"/>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What processor are you using? Adding attributes when using `xsl:copy` should work fine.